# Receive Redis streams data using Spring & Lettuce

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I have the below `Spring boot` code to receive values whenever a Redis stream is appended with new record. The problem is receiver never receives any message, also, the subscriber, when checked with `subscriber.isActive()`, is always inactive. Whats wrong in this code? What did I miss? [Doc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reference/redis-streams.adoc#pubsub) for reference.

On spring boot start, initialize the necessary redis resources

Lettuce connection factory

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory("127.0.0.1", 6379);
}
```

RedisTemplate from the connection factory

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

Rest controller to append data to redis stream

```
@PutMapping("/{name}")
public String post(@PathVariable String name) {
    return redisTemplate.opsForStream().add(StreamRecords.newRecord().in("streamx").ofObject(name)).getValue();
}
```

JMS style imperative message listener

```
@Component
public class MyStreamListener implements StreamListener<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> {

@Override
public void onMessage(MapRecord<String, String, String> message) {
    System.out.println("message received: " + message.getValue());
}

}
```

Initialize the listener

```
  @Bean
public Subscription listener(MyStreamListener streamListener, RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) throws InterruptedException {
    StreamMessageListenerContainer<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> container = StreamMessageListenerContainer
            .create(redisConnectionFactory);
    Subscription subscription = container.receive(Consumer.from("my-group-1", "consumer-1"),
            StreamOffset.create("streamx", ReadOffset.latest())), streamListener);
    System.out.println(subscription.isActive()); // always false
    return subscription;
}
```

Though, I am able to append to the stream through api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important step is, start the `StreamMessageListenerContainer` after the subscription is done.

```
container.start();
```

Comment: Where did you find this from? I spent 30+ mins trying to figure out myself. Unfortunately spring doc was not helpful

Comment: The [Spring document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.streams.receive.containers) is so poorly written. It doens't even remind us to start the container.

Comment: Not only the Spring docs, even the lib doc was poor. I think I found from Java docs.

Comment: I am facing issue, on redis rserver restart subscription is lost and consumer don't automatically subscribe again. Any idea about this?

Comment: Not sure, you can ask it as a separate question